# Which of these Java conventions has higher priority?

Tags: java

Declaring `final` variables together at the top of the class.

**or**

Limiting scope of those variables by declaring within their respective methods.

Comment: the two options don't have the same semantics - so they aren't comparable...

Comment: This question seems to be subjective and opinion only, the compiler doesn't care - so priority for what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a matter of convention - it's a matter of what's logical state in the object.

If a variable is logically part of the state of an object, it should be declared as a field - and yes, conventionally put at the top of the file.

If it's only part of the *local* state of the method, then it would be mad to declare it as a field. This isn't in conflict with the convention of where you put fields - it's simply a matter of choosing whether it's a field or a local variable.

Within a *method*, I see a lot of novice Java programmers declaring all their variables at the top of the method - whereas a more useful habit in my view is to declare a variable as late as possible, and with as small a scope as possible.

Comment: I'm in that novice category you mention and I'm often declaring final variables as fields. Not sure where I got the habit but I started wondering why/when I could reduce their scope. Your answer makes perfect sense. Thank you.

Comment: @es0329: There's nothing wrong with final fields per se (indeed, typically my fields are final too) - so long as they're logically part of the state of the object.